# using factories for nested one to many relations in laravel 7

Tags: factory, laravel-7

i have a problem from using factories For three nested levels in a one-to-many relationship
these are my migrations:

```
    Schema::create('main_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name', 100)->nullable(false);
    });

    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name', 100)->nullable(false);

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('main_category_id');
        $table->foreign('main_category_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('main_categories')
            ->cascadeOnDelete();
    });

    Schema::create('sub_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name', 100)->nullable(false);

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
        $table->foreign('category_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('categories')
            ->cascadeOnDelete();
    });
```

and these are my models

```
class MainCategory extends Model
{
   ...

   public function categories()
   {
       return $this->hasMany(Category::class);
   }
}

class Category extends Model
{
    ...

    public function MainCategory()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(MainCategory::class);
    }

    public function subCategories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SubCategory::class);
    }
}

class SubCategory extends Model
{
    ...

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
}
```

these are my factories:

```
$factory->define(MainCategory::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name'=>$faker->name
    ];
});
$factory->define(Category::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name
    ];
});
$factory->define(SubCategory::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name
    ];
});
```

and i use these factories like this. i should say , i want when MainCategory rows created, immediately create Category how has one to many relation with MainCategory and after that SubCategory should create how has one to many relation with Category.
I don't know where is my mistake:

```
factory(MainCategory::class, 5)->create()->each(function ($mainCategory) {
    $mainCategory->categories()->saveMany(factory(Category::class, 7)->make()->each(function ($category){
        $category->subCategories()->saveMany(factory(SubCategory::class, 7)->make());
    }));
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit late to answer you, but it may be useful for another Laravel developer. I had the same problem as you, and after some thought, I suggest you take a "break" in your code. Like this:

```
factory(MainCategory::class, 5)->create()->each(function ($mainCategory) {

    $mainCategory->categories()->saveMany(factory(Category::class, 7)->make();
    // Break
    $mainCategory->categories->each(function ($category){

        $category->subCategories()->saveMany(factory(SubCategory::class, 7)->make());
        // Break
        // $category->subcategories->each(function ($sub){
        //     ....
        // });

    }));

});
```

Now you can do a lot of relations.